# Spring validator default message codes not resolving

Tags: validation, spring, resources, message

I have a custom spring validator which has the following default message:

```
public @interface FieldMatch {
    String message() default "au.com.xxx.website.FieldMatchValidation";
...
```

The problem I'm having is that the message code is not being resolved and <form:error...> is simply displaying the code rather than the message (Which is in a properties file which is being used by a ResourceBundleMessageSource).

I've also tried this as

```
    String message() default "{au.com.xxx.website.FieldMatchValidation}";
```

Which causes the message source to crash with an exception indicating that it thinks that the "{}" brackets should contain a number because it thinks it's a parameter place holder.

I think that the issue is that the message code is not being seen as a message code and therefore not resolved, but I cannot figure out why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. It seams that this is all being handled by the hibernate validators and they are hard coded to look for a resource file called ValidationMessages.properties. Once I added that and placed the messages in it, everything started working.